# What's the scope of an item in an JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with scopes in JavaScript and I was curious about something I ran across when calling a function from an array. In the below example I work with three different scopes. One bound to an Object called foobar, one bound to window and then a third one which actually refers to the function itself. I'm just curious why the function is scoped to itself and not to the global window object. Is it because Array access is a function call itself so the stored function is in a local scope?

```
var foobar = {
  doWork: function() {
      console.log('doing some work...');
      console.log(this);
  }
}

foobar.doWork(); // `this` will refer to foobar

var doWorkClone = foobar.doWork;
doWorkClone(); // `this` will refer to window

var workClones = [];
workClones.push(foobar.doWork);
workClones[0](); // `this` will refer to the doWork function itself
```

Comment: That value of `this` has nothing to do with *scope*

Comment: Functions are never really "bound" to anything in JavaScript.  The value of `this` is determined upon each function call based on the situation.

Comment: Also I don't think your last assertion is really true ...

Comment: "`this` will refer to the doWork function itself" — No, it won't. Note the `[` and `]` in the output. It refers to `workClones`

Comment: See [the applicable documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @Pointy Functions can have a bound `this`, at least from ECMAScript 5 onwards with the `bind()` method.

Comment: @Humberto: Strictly speaking that's just a trick. The function that `.bind` returns calls the original function with a predefined `this` - but neither of the two functions have a `this` value bound, technically.

Comment: @Humberto well, that's still not really true - the function returned from `.bind` can be invoked with `this` set to anything, but internally it always explicitly forces `this` to be set to something in particular when the ultimate target function is invoked. However the use of the word "bind" for the function name does make things confusing. It's still the case that the binding is really unlike the way C++ style class membership works.

Comment: @Pointy and @pimvdb: thanks for the clarification. I'd only like to add that, in the context of the OP code (no pun intended), and applying `doWork.bind()`, the `console.log(this)` call would produce consistent results regardless of how the function is called.

Comment: @Humberto oh yes, you're definitely correct about the behavior - really we're just being picky about the terminology :-)

Comment: Regarding the first comment, just so I'm clear, `this` is created by the context and is not a variable in the scope chain, correct? I've often mixed the terms context and scope I guess :[

Comment: @robdodson: In a function you *always* have one `this` value or another. So the concept of scope (which variables are available by inner functions, etc.) is not applicable. `this` is generated when the function is called. See this recursive example: http://jsfiddle.net/W4xpH/. The same function is called, but it has a different `this` value in each call.

Comment: @pimvdb Ok. I think this article: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/ and your comment helped solidify things for me. context is the neighborhood, scope is the boundaries and who is available in that neighborhood (the scope chain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They behave the same way. In `a.b()`, the function `a.b` is called with `this` set to `a`.

```
foobar.doWork();  // function is `foobar.doWork`, `this` is `foobar`
workClones[0]();  // function is `workClones[0]`, `this` is `workClones`
```

This is because the `.` and `[]` notation are functionally the same thing. It does not matter which one you use, nor does it matter whether you're dealing with an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

to understand this, litteraly, it might be helpfull to see how the js works under the hood.

when you write `f(args)`, js will execute `f.call(this, args)`. Hence `this` always refers to where you call the function from.

In your case:

```
foobar.doWork()   --> foobar
doWorkClone()     --> window or wrapping expression
workClones[0]()   --> "0" is in workClones, so workClones
```

Comment: The examples are correct but I don't fully agree with your `this` reasoning. Surely `foobar.doWork.call(this)` is different.

Comment: `f(args)` is *not* like `f.call(this, args)` at all. Or were you referring to a special case? In general it's completely wrong.

Comment: Of course "this" is different when you type it down (as you overwrite the "this" passed by default). We can argue than "this" is actually the parent object, but I won't as your your explanation is *already* way more clear.